# How to delete/customize imported demo content from a theme or add my own?

Tags: posts, customization, themes

I'm new to WordPress. I installed a new theme and there was no content on the page, then I imported demo data, my database got populated with a bunch of content and there are now many different sections added on the homepage (for example this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyB8o.png)

I don't understand how can I delete this content and add my own? I tried deleting almost all .php files from /themes/my_theme and wp_posts from the database but this content didn't change.

If I wanted to delete this 'Who are we' section how would I do it and add my own?

Comment: What is the theme name?

Comment: The name is: Rentit

Comment: Don't think the theme has anything to do with it.  Think the data is in the database and the theme should just be the rendering engine, from what I've always been told.

Answer (score 0):

With your theme you got a docs page with instructions how to edit the pages and use the theme. Don't delete any php files, you have visual page builder.

If you will navigate into https://your-domain/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page you should see the list of pages which were created by importing the demo content.

If you can't find the docs or not sure how to use it, contact the [support](https://themeforest.net/item/rent-it-car-rental-template-with-rtl-support/11839946/support).

Comment: If the answer helped you could "accept" and "up vote" it :)

Comment: I upovted it, but it's not showing becuase I don't have enough karma. I will do that when I get it! You got some points for it.